# Localizing Default Data Annotations

Tags: asp.net-core, localization, westwind-globalization

We're using ASP.Net Core 2.2 and Westwind Globalization.

I was wondering if there's a way to use these two to override the default attributes, such as StringLength in the model?

We're updating the built in items, such as "ModelBindingMessageProvider.SetValueIsInvalidAccessor" but these appear to be elsewhere.

I can update them by adding a "ModelMetadataDetailsProviders" but that caches after first run, so only the first language can be used.

I'm hoping to use the database resources.

Any help here appreciated.

Thanks,
David

Comment: Just to add to this, I'm just trying to override the default ones as opposed to adding ErrorMessage etc. to every place I have this in the system.